# Position floating panel/textbox on Google Map

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to position a floating panel textbox on a Google Map.  I want the textbox position in the red box in the image below:

[image]

I can get the floating panel to appear above the map container (see code below).

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container" id="floating-panel">
    <input id="address" type="text" value="">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search">
</div>

<div id="map" class="class--map">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.class--map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

I have tried to move the floating panel into the map container like this:

```
<div id="map" class="class--map">
    <div class="container" id="floating-panel">
        <input id="address" type="text" value="">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search">
    </div>
</div>
```

But this hides the panel and textbox behind the map.

How is it best to get the panel/textbox on the map in the right position?

Comment: You may need to include `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 5;` in your CSS to position the div over the map. The floating panel div needs to be separate from the map div. The Google Maps APIs official documentation has several [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) that show this in action

Comment: @Preston - I've adjusted the position, z-index and the top' in the CSS like so, which works... '.floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 10;
}'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to add it as a [Custom Control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) to the map.

```
var controlDiv = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(controlDiv);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rkqx8z5e/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 45,
      lng: -100
    },
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };
  // Display a map on the page
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  // add floating-panel control
  var controlDiv = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(controlDiv);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.class--map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div class="container" id="floating-panel">
  <input id="address" type="text" value="">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search">
</div>

<div id="map" class="class--map">
</div>
```